# Crash - EXC_BREAKPOINT(CODE=1) while posting the notification

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to fix the

> Thread 1 EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=0,subcode=0x18e0173f4)

When I'm posting a changeLoggingState Notification,

[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxwSq.png)

[Crash screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvNrw.png)

Comment: Why you're passing the object as 'NO' in postNotification?

Comment: post code instead of screenshots!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set to nil in selector?

```
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self
                                     selector:nil
                                         name:notificationName
                                       object:nil];
```

This maybe make this happen.